# Assign a block to more than 1 region in the main page

Tags: php, api, drupal, hook

**How do  i assign one menu block in different regions on the front page. I created a sub  theme using bootstrap theme. In that i have also created the following regions.Need:
 main menu in `Primary region`
 main menu in `Footer Quick Menu1` region**

```
regions[navigation]         = 'Navigation'
regions[header]             = 'Top Bar'
regions[highlighted]        = 'Highlighted'
regions[help]               = 'Help'
regions[content]            = 'Content'
regions[sidebar_first]      = 'Primary'
regions[sidebar_second]     = 'Secondary'
regions[footer]             = 'Footer'
regions[footer_first]       = 'Footer First'
regions[footer_second]      = 'Footer Second'
regions[footer_third]       = 'Footer Third'
regions[footer_fourth]      = 'Footer Fourth'
regions[footer quickmenu1]  = 'Footer Quick Menu1'
regions[footer quickmenu2]  = 'Footer Quick Menu2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal out of the box can only assign a block to one region. You'll want to take a look at a contributed module. I'd recommend taking a look at the excellent [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module. It will provide you with a more advanced blocks management tool and is relatively simple to use.

I've used this module on most of the Drupal sites I have developed in the past.

Comment: @satyabratasahoo glad it helped. Would you mind accepting my answer if it worked for you? Accepting answers on Stackoverflow helps others identify correct answers and will boost your own reputation a bit too.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [MultiBlock](http://drupal.org/project/multiblock) module, which allows you to have multiple instances of the same block.

From the project page:

> MultiBlock module solves this problem by allowing you to create multiple Block Instances of already existing blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Though assigning one block at different places if not possible but you can choose to make multiple instance by help of above said [Multiblock](http://drupal.org/project/multiblock) module or another way is to print the region at several place as per your need in TPL and render the output, this will also do your work..

Thanks

Comment: Yes dear @RajeeVK it will, but it will not an appropriate way to write in the hard code is there any options apart from that so that i could able to assign blocks to different regions.

Comment: @satyabratasahoo - What do you mean by "not an appropriate way"....doesn't we make our own TPL, if you don't do then you should just make multiple instance by above given module name..